# react-spring: using useChain to scale and translate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-spring

I am currently using useTransition to make my mobile navigation appear:

```
const MobileNav = ({show, toggle, styles}) => {
  let transition = useTransition(show, null, {
    from: {transform: 'translateY(-100%) scale(0.7)', ...styles},
    enter: {transform: 'translateY(0) scale(1)'},
    leave: {transform: 'translateY(100%) scale(0.7)'}
  })

  return (
    <>
      {transition.map(({item, props, key}) => {
        return item ? (
          <animated.div className="navbar__menu_mob" key={key} style={props}>
            ...someHtml
          </animated.div>
        ) : null
      })}
    </>
  )
}
```

With this code the scale and the translate animate at the same time. My end goal is to chain them so the `scale` is first then the `translateY` is after. From the examples by react-spring the best way seems to be wrapping the my first `animated.div` in another `animated.div` and chaining them using `useChain`.

I seem to be struggling to understand the best way to chain my animations together. Ideally I wouldn't have to wrap what I currently have in another `animated.div`. I could do with some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out without using useChain().

I used multi stage transitions:

```
let transition = useTransition(show, null, {
    from: {translate: '-100%', scale: 0.7, ...styles},
    enter: item => async(next) => {
      await next({translate: '0%'})
      await next({scale: 1})
    },
    leave: item => async(next) => {
      await next({scale: 0.7})
      await next({translate: '100%'})
    }
  })
```

Then I had to interpolate the styles like so:

```
{transition.map(({item, props, key}) => {
        return item ? (
          <animated.div className="navbar__menu_mob" key={key} style={{
            transform: interpolate([
              props.translate.interpolate(v => `translateY(${v})`),
              props.scale.interpolate(v => `scale(${v})`)
            ], (translate, scale) => `${translate} ${scale}`),
            ...props
            }}></animated.div> )
        : null })}
```